# REST services in a ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I come from a `RubyOnRails` background so sorry if this looks like a silly question:

Let's say we are creating our app in `ASP.NET MVC` and we need to develop some RESTful web services to give us some `JSON` that we can use in our app.

How do you create those services? Is it `WCF` ? 
In `Ruby` we actually used `Java-Jersey` for the service side but in my current work place it is a .NET shop with strong experience in Silverlight and RIA Services. so what is the NET approach of web services for `ASP.NET MVC` ?

Comment: You can use WCF, but the cool kids are using Web API. It's much more focused on playing well with HTTP.

Comment: @ChrisHardie : I had heard of "Web API" but couldn't understand what does it do. Is it for writing web services in .NET? and is it RESTful?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

Comment: @DevWannaBe http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF is a super powerful but incredibly complex communication framework that allows systems to talk over multiple protocols. It sounded cool during Microsoft's initial pitch, but there is an incredible amount of overhead just to, say, push a scalar across the wire. WCF certainly still has its place, but it's a beast of a framework.

Given how much effort there is in integrating it into a solution, some MVC developers noticed that, Hey! I can just return a `JsonResult` from my MVC controller and have my AJAX scripts consume that. Quick and dirty!

Microsoft then refined the experience with Web API, which is focused solely on developing HTTP services. It's architected quite similarly with MVC, which makes it pretty darned easy to pick up. It is typically RESTful, but doesn't need to be. By design it works really, really well with HTTP - remember, HTTP is an application protocol as well as a transport protocol.

There is also neat stuff like how it takes care of serialization for you - if the client wants XML, Web API gives it XML. If the client wants JSON, Web API gives it JSON. With a little work, you can even come up with custom serialization formats!

So, before I go off on one of the many tangents about how awesome sauce Web API is, let me say that if you are looking for a simple, powerful framework that can deliver RESTful services over HTTP, then Web API is your solution.

http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Ok so what I need is really this WebAPI. Now another question: I searched on Amazon and there are many books on WebAPI and then there is WebAPI2 and then ASP.NET WebAPI, etc...I guess some of them are older ones that have got replaced, so what is the new one? Is it something named like"ASP.NET MVC WebAPI 2" ?

Comment: Web Api 2 is the latest major release: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases Use Nuget to install the latest version into your solution.